# Как изменить маршрут к bootstrap.css в Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

Даже если в AssetBondle все выключить, то все равно грузятся фалы bootstrap.css и bootstrap.js. Я в принципе не против, чтоб они грузились, но я собираю свой bootstrap из less файлов, и мне всего-то хотелось бы изменить путь к этому файлу. Как это сделать правильно?

Подключаю только свои файлы css в AssetBundle:

```
namespace app\assets; 

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

/**
 * @author Qiang Xue <qiang.xue@gmail.com>
 * @since 2.0
 */
class RazzAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/my_bootstrap.css',
        'css/main.css',
    ];
    public $js = [

    ];

}
```

На странице грузится два bootstrap файла:

```
<link href="/yii2/css/my_bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/yii2/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/yii2/assets/b6651f1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/yii2/assets/4327c007/toolbar.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
```

Бесит это навязывание своего способа добавления стилей в Yii2. Хотя, если решить эту проблему, может, и будет удобно.

Comment: Пути для нормализованной статики задаются через [AssetManager](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/AssetManager.php#L73). Если нормализация не требуется, то необходимо [указать в конифге](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/structure-assets.md#customizing-asset-bundles-) для вашего бандла `RazzAsset` свойство `sourcePath`, как `null`.

Comment: @Razzwan Обычно такое бывает. если какой-то виджет требует bootstrap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В конфиг **web.php**

Добавьте

```
'components' => [
    'assetManager' => [
        'bundles' => [
            'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' => [
                'css' => []
            ]
        ]
    ],
    ...
],
```

Выключит bootstrap.css для всех виджетов.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Получилось!